# Лицензия MIT и GitHub

Tags: github, лицензирование, opensource, авторские-права

Если в моем проекте есть сторонние модули слегка (а некоторые не слегка) модифицированные у которых лицензия MIT, могу ли я вместе с ними выкладывать и лицензировать свой проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да.

Вы можете публиковать, распространять и сублицензировать программное обеспечение, имеющее [лицензию MIT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_MIT).

Но следует учесть, что Вы должны сохранить уведомление об авторском праве на сторонние модули и включить его во все копии или значимые части Вашего Программного обеспечения.

---

Перевод текста лицензии:

> Copyright (c) <год> <владельцы прав>
>
> Данная лицензия разрешает лицам, получившим копию данного программного
>   обеспечения и сопутствующей документации (в дальнейшем именуемыми
>   «Программное обеспечение»), безвозмездно использовать Программное
>   обеспечение без ограничений, включая неограниченное право на
>   использование, копирование, изменение, слияние, публикацию,
>   распространение, сублицензирование и/или продажу копий Программного
>   обеспечения, а также лицам, которым предоставляется данное Программное
>   обеспечение, при соблюдении следующих условий:
>
> Указанное выше уведомление об авторском праве и данные условия должны
>   быть включены во все копии или значимые части данного Программного
>   обеспечения.
>
> ДАННОЕ ПРОГРАММНОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРЕДОСТАВЛЯЕТСЯ «КАК ЕСТЬ», БЕЗ
>   КАКИХ-ЛИБО ГАРАНТИЙ, ЯВНО ВЫРАЖЕННЫХ ИЛИ ПОДРАЗУМЕВАЕМЫХ, ВКЛЮЧАЯ
>   ГАРАНТИИ ТОВАРНОЙ ПРИГОДНОСТИ, СООТВЕТСТВИЯ ПО ЕГО КОНКРЕТНОМУ
>   НАЗНАЧЕНИЮ И ОТСУТСТВИЯ НАРУШЕНИЙ, НО НЕ ОГРАНИЧИВАЯСЬ ИМИ. НИ В КАКОМ
>   СЛУЧАЕ АВТОРЫ ИЛИ ПРАВООБЛАДАТЕЛИ НЕ НЕСУТ ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТИ ПО
>   КАКИМ-ЛИБО ИСКАМ, ЗА УЩЕРБ ИЛИ ПО ИНЫМ ТРЕБОВАНИЯМ, В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ, ПРИ
>   ДЕЙСТВИИ КОНТРАКТА, ДЕЛИКТЕ ИЛИ ИНОЙ СИТУАЦИИ, ВОЗНИКШИМ ИЗ-ЗА
>   ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ ПРОГРАММНОГО ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЯ ИЛИ ИНЫХ ДЕЙСТВИЙ С ПРОГРАММНЫМ
>   ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕМ.